# "Get smart in something", "get smart about something" or "get smart with something"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which preposition I use after smart: in, about, or with when specifying something the person wants to be knowlegeable about. For example:

> I want to get smart **in** math.
>
> I want to get smart **about** math.
>
> I want to get smart **with** math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of OP's examples sound idiomatic to me. We don't generally talk about *getting / becoming* "smart" anyway (you're either smart or you're not, same as you're either tall or not), and we don't usually restrict the scope of adjectival "smart" to a specific subject (being "smart" implies having high *general* intelligence).

To a lesser extent, the same applies to "clever" - we usually say *He's **good** at maths* rather than *He's **smart / clever** at maths*. There's not really a "preferred" preposition for ***smart ??? [subject]*** because we don't often use that format anyway.

In short, "smart" *(=clever, bright, intelligent)* is the wrong adjective. It's better to use something like "proficient" *(=skilled, accomplished, expert).* And check out [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proficient%20*%20math&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing that both ***in*** and ***at*** occur with "proficient".

---

(For the avoidance of doubt, note that I speak and write *British* English *(**BrE**)*, as opposed to "American" *(**AmE**)*. With ***color / colour*** the difference is only in ***writing***, but ***math / maths*** reflects what we usually ***say***.)

Comment: Nah - this is almost entirely a British/American English usage split. I don't necessarily change every such case to BrE when I'm doing "cut&paste", but obviously if I'm actually *typing* the words myself, I'll write ***maths*** and ***colour***, not ***math*** and ***color***.

Comment: I had no idea *maths* was BrE.  Thanks for explaining.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good+at+math%2C+good+at+maths&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3

Comment: You're probably not the only one, so thanks for calling attention to it - I'll add a brief note to the answer in case these comments get "tidied away" in the future.